# Download latest release version in version ranges

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using version-ranges to resolve latest release version but it downloads latest version(whether SNAPSHOT or RELEASE). I want to block snapshot and fetch latest release version only.

Is there any way to block SNAPSHOT download or if I can block publish of SNAPSHOT.

Thanks!

Comment: How have you called? What parameters? Checked for [use-latest-releases](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution.
Tried below dependency-
<dependency>
            <groupId>x.x.x</groupId>
            <artifactId>global-config</artifactId>
            <version>[0.0.1, 0.0.30)</version>
 </dependency>

Yes, tries versions-plugin as well, it just updates the pom.xml, changes to get reflected you need to build as separate step. Need to resolve version-ranges in one step only.

Comment: <repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>